# Laravel best practice for managing lookup tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I'm starting a new project. I need some advice on how to manage some lookup tables.

I have a table for managing a real estete properties; a house property can have associated many table of single element property, I think more than 20 tables and I don't want to manage a table for every element so what is the best practice?

Comment: What sort of elements? Stuff like "hot tub" and "garage" and "heated floors" and whatnot?

Comment: yes and in the UI form I need to display some select fields with one or multi-selection.

Comment: You'd likely have a `houses` table, an `elements` table with the available ones, and a `house_elements` pivot table linking the two via a many-to-many relationship. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: When you say you *don't want to manage a table for every element* what do you mean?       Do you want to reduce the number of tables? Or do you not want to make a model for each property? Are the properties similar enough to go into one table?  There's not enough detail here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have a object for real estate property with 49 attributes (code, price, square, location, type of sell, ecc..) in the UI I have fields like text, checkbox, selection singe and multiple, I'm looking for the best practice to organize the db tables and relations.